# Redirecting to another page in html using Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to go to another page in my angular website using a button when i press it
Content in .html file

```
 <button mat-raised-button (click)="goToPage('Login')">Sign up</button>
```

content of .ts file

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 constructor(private router: Router){ }

goToPage = function (pageName:string){
  this.router.navigate([`${pageName}`]);
}

  title = 'sign-up';
}
```

but i keep getting this error

[image]

And I am just wondering what i am doing wrong

Comment: Are you importing the [`RouterModule`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule)?

Comment: yes i am importing it

Comment: The `NullInjectorError` means that nothing is providing the `Router` service. Double check that `RouterModule` is being imported with `forRoot` (`RouterModule.forRoot()`) in the root of the app (`AppModule`). The static `forRoot` method takes care of providing the `Router` service.